# uniform prior on bayesian econometrics

Tags: bayesian

[![can anyone please help me to give a hint or a clue on how to solve this?][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35sNV.pngcan anyone please help me to give a hint or a clue on how to solve this?